# I have placed required into the select box but its not working. Below is my code

Tags: php, html

```
<select name="country" class="js-country" oninput="get_states(this.value)" required>
    <option>-- Country --</option>
    <?php
      if(isset($countries)&&  $countries):?>
        <?php foreach ($countries as $row):?>                                                                       
           <option value="<?=$row->id?>" ><?=$row->country?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif;?>
</select><br><br>
```

Although the required is added but still its not functioning properly. User still be able to move forward without filling country or state details.

Comment: FWIW: `if(isset($countries)&&  $countries)`  `if (!empty($countries))`

Comment: Tell us what you mean by "not functioning properly". What *does* it do, what do you *expect* it to do?

Comment: When providing an [mcve], please make it *minimal*. Your question is about the interaction between HTML and the browser. The PHP doesn't matter. You should show us the resulting HTML instead.

Comment: I am new to this platform, how it works I am not sure but this is the minimal code I have provided. All rest of the programming is working at the backend in php.

Comment: @NishantSaxena — Please pay attention to the last two sentences of my previous comment. Also the part headed "Help others reproduce the problem" of [ask]. Including PHP (especially with variables not defined in the code provided) instead of just including HTML makes it harder for people to understand and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select):

> required
>
> A Boolean attribute indicating that an option with a non-empty string value must be selected.

Assuming that `$row->id` is never going to give you an empty string, you don't have any options which meet that criteria.

I'm assuming you want to stop `<option>-- Country --</option>` being selected, but that option's value is `-- Country --`, not an empty string.

You need to be explicit if you want the value to be different from the label:

```
<option value="">-- Country --</option>
```

Here's a live demo:

```html
<form>
  <select required name=foo>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>

  <select required name=foo>
    <option value="">Empty String</option>
    <option>Three</option>
  </select>

  <button>Compare</button>
</form>
```